# Android ListView Updated by AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I'm populating a ListView from DB. The recordset from the DB contains the Zipcode which is then transformed into City and State using google map api and then set to Listview Item.

I need to be able to set the value that is being returned from the background class in Listview. Any guidance would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < zipcodes.getLength(); i++) {
GetCityStateInfoFromPostalCode getCityStateInfoFromPostalCode = new GetCityStateInfoFromPostalCode(getActivity(), "110001", "ta");
String mCityState = getCityStateInfoFromPostalCode.getCityState();

}
```

Here's Background Class that fetches the info from Google maps api

```
public class GetCityStateInfoFromPostalCode extends AsyncTaskLoader<String> {

private String URL;
private String mState = "";
private String mCity = "";
private Context mContext;

public String getCityState() {
    return mCityState;
}

private String mCityState = "";

public GetCityStateInfoFromPostalCode(Context context, String postalCode, String language) {

    super(context);
    this.mContext = context;
    URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:" + postalCode + "&language=" + language;

    // Kick start the load process
    forceLoad();
}

public String loadInBackground() {
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray jsonRootArray;
    JSONArray jsonAdressArray;

    JSONObject addressComponentCityObject;
    JSONObject addressComponentStateObject;

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
    httpGet.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");

    try {

        HttpResponse resp = client.execute(httpGet);
        String json = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

        addressComponentCityObject = new JSONObject();
        addressComponentStateObject = new JSONObject();

        jsonRootArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

        //This points to "0"
        JSONObject rootJson = jsonRootArray.getJSONObject(0);

        //This points to address components
        jsonAdressArray = rootJson.getJSONArray("address_components");

        //This points to Object 1 (Second object of the jsonAddressArray)
        addressComponentCityObject = jsonAdressArray.getJSONObject(1);
        mCity = addressComponentCityObject.getString("long_name");

        addressComponentStateObject = jsonAdressArray.getJSONObject(3);
        mState = addressComponentStateObject.getString("long_name");



    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // Handle error here
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.mCityState = mCity + ", " + mState;
    return mCityState;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with AsyncTask you can generate and override the methods below :

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
    super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

}
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: I'm using "AsyncTaskLoader" - onPreExecute() and onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) doesnt seem to be available

Comment: Try to change the AsyncTaskLoader to be AsyncTask

Comment: No joy. Unable to get the desired result. Stuck.

Comment: which way you are using AsyncTaskLoader or the AsyncTask ?

Comment: If the AyncTaskLoader , once you generate the loadInBackgroung method add the @Override above it . And use the method deliverResult(Object data) , one more thing , i see also that these methods created to return an Object so you will also need to change that as well to align it with whatever you want .

Comment: Take a look at this example : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html